# Correctly implementing pan and zoom in libgdx

Tags: libgdx, orthographic

I am almost done with my first libgdx 2d game, only this is missing.
Currently I have my main `GameScreen`, which contains 3 stages (rendered in this order):

- GameStage

Contains game actors, map, etc. Basically the game itself.

- InfoStage

All controls and information about the game, so called "hud".

- DialogStage

For displaying dialogs so that they are on top of everything.

I am using single `OrthographicCamera` and viewport of size necessary to display whole map and FitViewport to make sure everything works on resize too or if ratio changes.

Now I would like to make changes so that `InfoStage` and `DialogStage` stay pretty much like this - `fixed` on screen and allow `GameStage` zooming and pan to move around.

Firstly what does that mean for viewport and camera?
Does that mean I will have camera+viewport pair for `InfoStage` and `DialogStage` and different camera + viewport pair for `GameStage`?

Second and most importantly - how to implement zoom and pan for this stage? I've seen some similar questions, but implementations haven't really worked for me and I also didn't like them.
It feels like there could be simple separated class to do this - maybe `GestureListener` or `EventListener`/`InputProcessor` with passed `Camera`/`Viewport` to do all the work automatically.
I found [CameraInputController](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/utils/CameraInputController.html) which does something similar so I guess that can be a bit of lead.
Has anyone implemented this component? If not, what would you advise to do?

Comment: It would be very weird to be using the same camera for your game and your UI. Use an ExtendViewport for your game so it can use the whole screen. I haven't implemented gesture zooms for a camera. Since you're using Stage for your game, you're stuck using a Viewport rather than just a Camera. I would start by wrapping an ExtendViewport with a class that can adjust the viewport's world width and height based on some zoom parameter. Zooming closer means shrinking the world size of the viewport.

Comment: I agree there should be more cameras, what do you mean stuck because of using `Stage`? What's alternative? I am also posting class that is handling pan/zoom.

Comment: Stage requires you to use Viewport. If you don’t use Stage for your game you have the freedom to manage the camera without conforming to how Viewport works. That’s all I mean. It’s still achievable either way.

Answer (score 0):

So far I made `GestureListener`, which handles `zoom` and `pan`, making sure you never zoom out too far and you can never pan out of map, works pretty smooth, but probably doesn't cover all the possibilities like if y axis is rotated.
If you can call `fitBounds` separately after resize so that world clips in case it needs. I will try to update class as I get it cleaner and more flexible. Pretty sure this `scale()` method has to have build-in alternative in engine.
Another thing I added is `ScrollInputListener`, which can listen to mouse scroll and perform zoom.

Just add this class wrapped into `GestureDetector` and add to your input multiplexer. I am using it with `FillViewport`.

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera
import com.badlogic.gdx.input.GestureDetector
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.Viewport
class ScrollInputListener(
        val camera: OrthographicCamera,
        val panGestureListener: PanGestureListener
) : InputAdapter() {


    fun amountToZoom(amount: Int): Float {
        return (1.0f + amount.toFloat() / 10f)
    }

    override fun scrolled(amount: Int): Boolean {
        val newZoom = camera.zoom * amountToZoom(amount)
        return panGestureListener.doZoomIfAllowed(newZoom)
    }
}


class CameraMovement(val x: Float, val y: Float) {
    private fun shouldMove(): Boolean {
        return  x!= 0f || y != 0f
    }

    fun move(camera: OrthographicCamera, scale: Float): Boolean {
        if (shouldMove()) {
            camera.translate(-x / scale, y / scale)
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}

val Viewport.targetRatio: Float
    get() {
        return Gdx.graphics.height.toFloat() / this.worldHeight.toFloat()
    }

val Viewport.sourceRatio: Float
    get() {
        return Gdx.graphics.width.toFloat() / this.worldWidth.toFloat()
    }

fun Viewport.scale(): Float {
    return if (targetRatio < sourceRatio) Gdx.graphics.width.toFloat() / this.worldWidth.toFloat() else Gdx.graphics.height.toFloat() / this.worldHeight.toFloat()
}

class PanGestureListener(
        val camera: OrthographicCamera,
        val viewport: Viewport,
        val minWorldRatio: Double = 0.5
) : GestureDetector.GestureAdapter() {

    override fun pan(x: Float, y: Float, deltaX: Float, deltaY: Float): Boolean {
        val scale = viewport.scale()
        return fitBounds(scale, deltaX, deltaY).move(camera, scale)
    }

    fun fitBounds(scale: Float = viewport.scale(), deltaX: Float = 0f, deltaY: Float = 0f): CameraMovement {
        val mapLeft = 0
        val mapRight = viewport.worldWidth / camera.zoom
        val mapTop = 0
        val mapBottom = viewport.worldHeight / camera.zoom

        val cameraHalfWidth = if (viewport.targetRatio < viewport.sourceRatio) {
            camera.viewportWidth / 2f
        } else {
            camera.viewportWidth / 2f * (viewport.sourceRatio / viewport.targetRatio)
        }
        val cameraHalfHeight = if (viewport.targetRatio < viewport.sourceRatio) {
            camera.viewportHeight / 2f * (viewport.targetRatio / viewport.sourceRatio)
        } else {
            camera.viewportHeight / 2f
        }
        var xMovement = deltaX
        var yMovement = deltaY

        if ((camera.position.x - deltaX / scale) / camera.zoom - cameraHalfWidth < mapLeft) {
            camera.position.x = (mapLeft + cameraHalfWidth) * camera.zoom
            xMovement = 0f
        }
        if ((camera.position.x - deltaX / scale) / camera.zoom + cameraHalfWidth > mapRight) {
            camera.position.x = (mapRight - cameraHalfWidth) * camera.zoom
            xMovement = 0f
        }

        if ((camera.position.y + deltaY / scale) / camera.zoom - cameraHalfHeight < mapTop) {
            camera.position.y = (mapTop + cameraHalfHeight) * camera.zoom
            yMovement = 0f
        }
        if ((camera.position.y + deltaY / scale) / camera.zoom + cameraHalfHeight > mapBottom) {
            camera.position.y = (mapBottom - cameraHalfHeight) * camera.zoom
            yMovement = 0f
        }
        return CameraMovement(xMovement, yMovement)
    }

    var initialZoom = camera.zoom

    internal fun checkZoom(newZoom: Float, scale: Float = viewport.scale()): Boolean {
        if (
                viewport.worldWidth * scale * newZoom > Gdx.graphics.width &&
                viewport.worldHeight * scale * newZoom > Gdx.graphics.height
        ) {
            return false
        }
        if (
                viewport.worldWidth * scale * newZoom < Gdx.graphics.width * minWorldRatio &&
                viewport.worldHeight * scale * newZoom < Gdx.graphics.height * minWorldRatio
        ) {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    override fun zoom(initialDistance: Float, distance: Float): Boolean {
        val newZoom = initialZoom * initialDistance / distance
        val scale = viewport.scale()
        return doZoomIfAllowed(newZoom, scale)
    }

    fun doZoomIfAllowed(newZoom: Float, scale: Float = viewport.scale()): Boolean {
        if (checkZoom(newZoom = newZoom, scale = scale)) {
            camera.zoom = newZoom
            fitBounds(scale = scale)
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    override fun touchDown(x: Float, y: Float, pointer: Int, button: Int): Boolean {
        initialZoom = camera.zoom
        return super.touchDown(x, y, pointer, button)
    }
}
```